# Class not found Error with Yii 1 Extension in a Yii 2 Application

Tags: php, yii, yii2, namespaces, yii-extensions

I've seen similar questions, but nothing that seemed to answer my question, so hopefully this isn't a duplicate. I'm running a Yii 2 application and wanted to make use of a Yii 1 extension (EGMap) The instructions for EGMap say to unzip it to the protected/extensions folder and then use import statements to access it.

From what I read, it seemed to me that putting EGMap in my vendor folder would be acceptable and that if I gave a Class in there (say EGMapTest) a namespace, I could access it via use statements. I tried a bunch of different namespaces and use statements, but I thought just

```
namespace vendor;
```

in my EGMapTest class and then

```
use vendor\EGMapTest
```

in the file I want to use the extension would work, but I get a "Class 'vendor/EGMapTest' not found error. Is there some other reason or something I'm overlooking about Yii 1 apps that's a problem or do I not understand namespaces correctly? Sorry if this is something very simple, but any help or guidance is appreciated!

Comment: you cant drag&drop the extension from yii1 to vendor folder to be used inside yii2 there is a lot of difference you can use [**`THIS EXTENSION`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-google-maps-library/)

Comment: **Never, ever** touch manually `/vendor` directory!